# Multiple alignments of different equation types in math mode

Tags: math-mode, equations, horizontal-alignment, align

I was wondering how to correctly align the following equations at the `&` signs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat*}{3}
        &a_0 &= f^{\prime}(x^*) &{} \\
        &a_i, &{} i&=1,\ldots,p \text{ not assigned} \\
        &c_i &= g^{\prime}_i(x^*), \; i &\in B(x^*) \\
        &b_i &= h^{\prime}_i(x^*), \; i &= 1,\ldots, m.
    \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not writing `’` instead of `^{\prime}`?

Comment: @Mico: Actually, there isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want to put in again the punctuation, which I removed because it was inconsistent.

The following code

1. aligns left the variables;
2. aligns the = signs
3. aligns the *i*’s

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
&a_0 &&= f'(x^*)   &\qquad \\
&a_i &&            & i &=1,\dots,p \text{ not assigned} \\
&c_i &&= g'_i(x^*) & i &\in B(x^*) \\
&b_i &&= h'_i(x^*) & i &= 1,\dots, m
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Note the use of `'` instead of the awkward `^{\prime}` and of `\dots` instead of `\ldots`.

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Inspired by @egreg answer, I propose the following edited solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}    
\begin{alignat*}{3}
    a_0 &= f'(x^*),   &\quad \\
    a_i &,            &i &=1,\dots,p \text{ not assigned}, \\
    c_i &= g'_i(x^*), &i &\in B(x^*), \\
    b_i &= h'_i(x^*), &i &= 1,\dots, m.
\end{alignat*}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would argue that this looks better than the other answer. However, there is no “following code”, only a picture of the result.

Comment: @EikeSchulte Ops!

Comment: @egreg: I actually still would like to keep the commas after `g'_i(x^*)` and `h'_i(x^*)`.

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

[image]

Yo can achieve this by using `align*` and inserting space `\quad\`  after `a_i`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        a_0 & = f^{\prime}(x^*)                         \\
        a_i &\quad\ i = 1,\ldots,p \text{ not assigned} \\
        c_i & = g^{\prime}_i(x^*), \; i  \in B(x^*)     \\
        b_i & = h^{\prime}_i(x^*), \; i  = 1,\ldots, m.
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** considered OP and @Mico comments

Comment: I would like the equations to be aligned at the equal signs. the first equation does not seem to be aligned with the third and fourth equations.

Comment: @AEW - Just move the `&` alignment markers from the start of the line to just before the `=` and `\quad` particles, respectively. While you're at it, you may also want to drop the `,` (comma) after `a_i`.